# DeprecationWarning with selenium/geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

What does the DeprecationWarning mean?

Also it seems like if i delete the "elem" functions it kind of works but when the chrome tab opens with the link it immediatelly closes again

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui

import unittest
import time


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=r'C:\Users\iwanh\Desktop\Geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')

    def test_search_in_python_org_true(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://e-learning.nyc.gr/login/index.php")

        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        time.sleep(3)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        self.assertNotIn("No results found.", driver.page_source)

    def test_search_in_python_org_false(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("ljueragiuhoerg")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.assertIn("No results found.", driver.page_source)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Outputs of code
[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OkVd.png)
[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acpj2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `selenium4` as the key `executable_path` is deprecated you have to use an instance of the Service() class along with `ChromeDriverManager().install()` command as below.

**Pre-requisites**

- *Ensure that:* Selenium is upgraded to v4.0.0

**Solutions:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```